# Azure Site Recovery support and/or alternatives for VMs with encrypted drives

Tags: azure, disk-encryption

Azure Recovery docs indicate that encrypted drives are not supported,we currently utilize another hosting solution that uses vormetric to encrypt our data drives, is there any supported path that allows us to use site recovery in Azure without turning off encryption on the source host?  Are there any alternatives to bringing the VMWare VMs to Azure without rebuilding from scratch?  Our goal is to test migrate some servers from our current host to Azure to ascertain the cost and complexity of using Azure for a DR solution.   Note also that we don't have access to the vmware host, just the individual VMs.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable and deploy Azure disk encryption for Azure IaaS VMs, the following capabilities are disabled:

1. Azure disables encryption on OS and data drives for Windows IaaS VMS.
2. Azure disables encryption on data drivers for Linux IaaS VMs

If we are able to find a solution or workaround, I will update here.

If possible, turn off encryption on the source host if you want to migrate VMs from VMWARE to Azure.

It’s easy to migrate VMs from VMWARE to Azure. Please refer to the steps below.

1. Capturing VHD from VMWARE
2. Converting your VMware VM into a Hyper-V VM
3. Converting Hyper-V VM into Azure

For more information, please refer to the following article.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/07/14/step-by-step-migrating-from-vmware-to-microsoft-azure/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Regards,

Walter